# Django template loader unable to load template

Tags: django

I am getting a **TemplateDoesNotExistError**

I am new to Django development and have already spent hours trying to fix this issue without success.  Can anyone guide me?

My project is basilweb and my app within this project is basilapp.
I need to show a screen that gets the user for a "**gocker_setting**" if it's not already present in the session.

The form to ask the user for this gocker_setting displays correctly and I am able to retrieve the value properly in my view.  But when I next try to render the screen after the value is retrieved, I get a **TemplateDoesNotExistError at /genie/gocker**.

Template Loader post-mortem:
Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

```
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/sekhar/development/python-code/basilweb/basilapp/templates/{} (Source does not exist)

django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/sekhar/development/python-code/basilweb/python-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/{} (Source does not exist)

django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/sekhar/development/python-code/basilweb/python-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/{} (Source does not exist)

django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/sekhar/development/python-code/basilweb/basilapp/templates/{} (Source does not exist)
```

Here are the details of my setup

```
#settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'basilapp',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

# my directory structure
basilweb
    basilapp
        templates
            genie
                getgockersetting.html
                gocker.html

# basilweb/url.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('genie/', include('basilapp.genie.urls')),
    path('saras/', include('basilapp.saras.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]

# bailapp/genie/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('index', views.index, name='genie_index'),
    path('gocker', views.gocker, name='genie_gocker'),
]

# basilapp/genie/views.py
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def gocker(request):
    gocker_setting = None
    if "gocker_setting" in request.session:
        gocker_setting = request.session["gocker_setting"]
    else:
        # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
            form = forms.GockerSettingForm(request.POST)
            # check whether it's valid:
            if form.is_valid():
                gocker_setting = form.cleaned_data['gocker_setting']
                request.session["gocker_setting"] = gocker_setting
    if gocker_setting is None:
        form = forms.GockerSettingForm()
        return render(request, 'genie/getgockersetting.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        # gocker setting is present
        # do further processing
        # ******  This is where I get the ERROR ********
        return render('/genie/gocker.html', {})
```

Comment: `return render('/genie/gocker.html', {})` this should be like the upper one `return render(request, 'genie/getgockersetting.html', {'form': form})` that is `return render(request,'genie/gocker.html', {})`

Comment: Try: `return render(request, 'gocker.html')`